# Spring Security (Web Security Expressions) - Filtering on IP when Behind a Load Balancer

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security, jetty

We have an old Spring (~v3.0) app, that we have added some IP address filtering to with a Web Security Expression similar to:

```xml
<http use-expressions="true">    
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" filters="none" access="hasIpAddress('192.168.1.50')"/>
</http>
```

This works as expected, but behind a **load balancer**, everyone is disallowed from `/login` because the actual address that we want to filter on is in the `x-forwarded-host` header now.

Is there a way (via configuration) that I can make Spring Security aware of the `x-forwarded-*` headers? Or is there a different *Web Security Expression* I can use for this scenario?

PS. I lied..it's the `x-forwarded-for` header I really want to filter on

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Jetty to use the origin IP instead of proxy's IP, see [Jetty Documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/9.4.x/configuring-connectors.html):

> **X-Forward-for Configuration**
>
> The `X-Forwarded-for` header and associated headers are a de facto standard where intermediaries add HTTP headers to each request they forward to describe the originating connection. These headers can be interpreted by an instance of `ForwardedRequestCustomizer` which can be added to a `HttpConfiguration` as follows:
>
> ```
> <New id="httpConfig" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConfiguration">
>     <Set name="outputBufferSize">32768</Set>
>     <Set name="requestHeaderSize">8192</Set>
>     <Set name="responseHeaderSize">8192</Set>
>
>     <Call name="addCustomizer">
>         <Arg><New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.ForwardedRequestCustomizer"/></Arg>
>     </Call>
> </New>
> ```

and [`ForwardedRequestCustomizer`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/stable-9/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/ForwardedRequestCustomizer.html):

> Customize Requests for Proxy Forwarding.
>
> This customizer looks at at HTTP request for headers that indicate it has been forwarded by one or more proxies. Specifically handled are
>
> - `Forwarded`, as defined by rfc7239
> - `X-Forwarded-Host`
> - `X-Forwarded-Server`
> - `X-Forwarded-For`
> - `X-Forwarded-Proto`
> - `X-Proxied-Https`
>
> If these headers are present, then the `Request` object is updated so that the proxy is not seen as the other end point of the connection on which the request came
>
> Headers can also be defined so that forwarded SSL Session IDs and Cipher suites may be customised

Comment: That's definitely the right way to go, but after a few cracks, I can't seem to init a ForwardedRequestCustomizer via the [spring jetty module](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/frameworks.html#_jetty_spring_module)